# tileSize at 512 causes missing bottom half of tiles and shifting coordinates

Tags: leaflet

when I set "tileSize: 512" the bottom half of my map is not showing and the [0, 0] coordinate of my custom map shifts to 25% from top and left.
So I guess increasing the tileSize is not enough. Somwhere I'd have to tell the system, to realign the map. Or something. But where?
Thank you very much...

```
var huts = L.layerGroup();
    var hut00 = L.marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('This is <b>HTML</b>content').addTo(huts);

    bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(90, -180), new L.LatLng(-90, 180));

    var baseMap = L.tileLayer("mapTiles/{z}_{x}_{y}.jpg", {tileSize: 512, minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 4, noWrap: true});
    var pcMap = L.map('pcMapDiv', {
            layers: [baseMap, huts],
            center: bounds.getCenter(),
        zoom: 2,
            maxBounds: bounds,
            maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0
        });
    var baseMaps = {
        "Plan": baseMap,
    };
    var overlays = {'Hütten': huts};

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(pcMap);
```

Comment: It very probably depends on how your map tiles have been generated. Is the situation fine with default size? (256px) If not, then we probably need more information and screenshots about what your custom tiles look like.

Comment: pullmancity.mzgn.de It is a custom map of an amusement park where the entire thing is "the world" meaning the city spans over -90° to 90° and -180° to 180°. In the uploaded example I have tileSize on default (even though one tile jpg actually has 512x512px). Just for the client to see the thing working. But that means the map now shows only half of the possible resolution.

Comment: I dont know if this is the solution or just a workaround: I added "{tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 5, noWrap: true}" Seems to work...

Comment: I just uploded the new version with "zoomOffset: -1" to the server. Just FYI.